# paramiko.SSHClient.exec_command hangs

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, exec, paramiko

I need to just a start another Python script (eg: `second_python.py`) in a remote server. This `second_python.py` will wait for some request coming from other server. So just need to start the `start_python.py` and return back to first Python script and proceed. I used below script but the script is hanging after starting the `second_python.py`.

```
#First python script
import es_helper
def ConnectES(self,payload_script):
 self.es = es_helper.ESHelper(config.es_ip)      
 self.es.execute_script(config.es_script_path,config.es_script,payload_script)

#es_helper.py
def execute_command(self, cmd):
  LOG.debug("executing command '{}'".format(cmd))
  stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)
  return stdout.readlines(), stderr.readlines()

#This function used to start second python script
def execute_script(self,es_script_path,es_script,payload_script):
  self.execute_command('python {0}{1}{2} {0}{1}{3} > {0}{1}1.txt'.format(es_script_path,'/',es_script,es_script))


#client.py
def exec_command(
    self,
    command,
    bufsize=-1,
    timeout=None,
    get_pty=False,
    environment=None,
):

    chan = self._transport.open_session(timeout=timeout)
    if get_pty:
        chan.get_pty()
    chan.settimeout(timeout)
    if environment:
        chan.update_environment(environment)
    chan.exec_command(command)
    stdin = chan.makefile("wb", bufsize)
    stdout = chan.makefile("r", bufsize)
    stderr = chan.makefile_stderr("r", bufsize)
    return stdin, stdout, stderr
```

Expected Result : start the second python script and return to first python script

Answer (score 1):

The `readlines` waits for the command to complete. If you do not want to wait, remove the call.